# C#, is there even a need to pass an object by reference?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I am trying to refresh my understanding of C#. I have used Java before and passing by reference is a powerful tool that I truly miss in Java. However, I needed clarification if there is even a need to pass an object by reference and if there is a scenario where it may be helpful? Stackoverflow already has multiple questions around reference and they were truly enlightening, however, I was wondering if there is a scenario for passing objects by reference. Let me attach the code to better illustrate it.

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Update(int x) { x++; }
        public static void Update(ref int x) { x++; }
        public static void Update(Employee x) { x.msalary += 2000; }
        public static void Update(ref Employee x) { x.msalary += 2000; } //Do we even need this method? Is there a scenario where we might need this?

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int a = 0;

            Update(a);
            Console.WriteLine("T1  " + a.ToString()); //a is still 0

            Update(ref a);
            Console.WriteLine("T2  " + a.ToString());//a is 1

            Employee emp2 = new Employee("Brent", "1234", "Blue", 1000); //salary is 1000

            Update(emp2.msalary);
            Console.WriteLine("T3  " + emp2.msalary.ToString());//salary does not change.

            Update(ref emp2.msalary);
            Console.WriteLine("T4  "+emp2.msalary.ToString());//salary changes to 1001

            Update(emp2);
            Console.WriteLine("T5  " + emp2.msalary.ToString()); //This changes, as expected for objects.

            Update(ref emp2);
            Console.WriteLine("T6  " + emp2.msalary.ToString()); //This also changes. But is there a scenario where we might need this?


        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `Update(ref Employee x)` method can do `x = new Employee()`, and that change is reflected in the caller

Comment: The scenario is the same for both reference and value types - when you need to assign to the variable in the called function and have that be visible in the caller. You aren't assigning `x` in your `ref Employee` example so it's not required.

Comment: I would say for a value type only if you want to change the value and have it reflected outside of the scopre.   For a reference type only if you might make the current instance null or if you need to assign a new instance to the reference.

Comment: In your case the reference to Employee is not being modified.  You are only modifying the actual object but not the reference to it.

Comment: why would the useful scenarios in C# be any different to Java, did you think?

Comment: Notable how the highly voted comment is not correct.  Try declaring Employee as a *struct* to see the difference.

Comment: _"I was wondering if there is a scenario for passing objects by reference"_ -- that's not what `ref` is. As explained in numerous Q&A already, `ref` affects how the _parameter_ is passed, not the object the parameter may or may not refer to.

Comment: `ref` is often need in recursion.

Answer (score 7):

Calling it "ref" was in my opinion a mistake; the right way to think of this feature is that it *makes a local or parameter an alias to another variable*. That is, when you use `ref` you have just given *another name* to an existing variable.

So the question then is: under what circumstances does it make sense to modify *someone else's variable*?  Those are the circumstances in which you should use `ref`.

Back in historical times the main use case for `ref` was something like `bool TryParse(string s, out int x)` where you want to have two return values: a bool and an int. But that method was created in the C# 1 days before generics, nullables and tuples. The better practice now is: if you need to return a value type that could be invalid, return a nullable, and if you need to return two values, return a tuple. (Remember, `out` is just `ref` that requires writing before reading.)

What then is the current use case for `ref` in new code that uses tuples and nullable value types? There are some algorithms where you can gain a small amount of performance by reading and modifying a variable in another part of the data structure directly, but you need to pass around *which* variable needs reading and modifying. That is, `ref` should be used as a performance optimization for the implementation details of certain data types. (Remember that you cannot *permanently store* refs; you can only make a *local* an alias to another variable, and that local cannot have its lifetime extended! This greatly limits the use cases for refs.)

You can also use `ref` as a more clean, type-safe way to interoperate with unmanaged code that uses pointers as aliases for variables.

That's about it. I almost never use `ref` in mainstream, line-of-business code. It's there for when you need it, but you almost never do.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Eric. I have coded in C before, and ref reminded me of the pointer functionality in C. I thought that using ref might enhance code performance, but based on everyone's feedback, I will avoid using it.

Comment: @baleeghr00: IMHO, C language has no "passing by variable sharing" feature above, but C++ does.

Comment: What are pointers if not aliases to variables?

Comment: A variable associated with a memory storage location of type pointer in C/C++ contains the address (aka reference in C#) of an object. It is the same as  a variable of reference type in C#. An alias shares the same memory storage location.

Comment: `p` in `int* p;` is a pointer and `q`  in `int*& q = p;` is an alias of `p`.

Comment: Sure, but what I'm getting at is that if we have `int x = 123;` and `int *p = &x;` then `*p` is also a variable and moreover is an alias for `x`.  We don't need C++ references; they are just a pleasant sugar over pointers.

Comment: `void Do(int** alias){int y = 10; *alias = &y;} int main(){int x = 1; int* pointer = &x; Do(&pointer); std::cout << *pointer; }`

Comment: That right there is dangerously undefined behaviour. You'll note that the same program is impossible in C# using managed references; if you use `unsafe` then you are responsible for not doing stuff like this.

Comment: And of course you can write a much simpler version of this bad program: `int* bad() { int y = 1; return &y;} ...` It's always dangerous to make a pointer to a variable where the lifetime of the pointer is longer than the lifetime of the variable; C# has a variety of techniques for preventing that with `ref` locals.

Comment: What about `Try-` methods that return reference types that can be null? How would you define "today" an `INewDictionary<T>` interface, without a `TryGetValue` method?